# VBA Macro that would force equal two cells where one of them has a formula in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VBA macro that forces two cells (P24 & P25) to equal each other. This is normally done by any triggered action of change in value in either of the two cells controlled by the macro. But P24 cell has a formula in it ["=A6" (a drop downlist)] that is populating based on a dropdown list. When someone chooses an option in the dropdown list, it updates cell-1 due to its formula. But P25 does not update because the macro does not consider P24's formula update as a "triggered action", so the macro does not run (activate) and P25 does not get updated. Is there a way to get P25 to be updated when P24's formula value changes, not when the value of the cell as a whole changes? I hope that made sense.

**NOTE:** Just in case you are wondering, I cannot have a formula in P25 like in P24 because its value can change by a dropdown itself. I really do not want to have to explain that part of it. I just need what I have asked for. The purpose by request is only to create a popular selection by default but can be changed if needed.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
If Target.Address = "$P$24" Then
Application.EnableEvents = False
ActiveSheet.Cells.Cells(25, 16) = ActiveSheet.Cells(24, 16)
Application.EnableEvents = True
Else
If Target.Address = "$P$25" Then
Application.EnableEvents = False
ActiveSheet.Cells(24, 16) = ActiveSheet.Cells(25, 16)
Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to use the `Worksheet.Calculate` event for P24.

Comment: Btw once P25 is changed, you lose your formula in P24, right? Just checking that that's what you want to happen.

Comment: That is correct. I will look into the Worksheet. Calculate. Thanks for the advise and will report back with my findings and solutions if found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to make this work. I did not realize at first but I can choose any cell that changes to trigger the macro to process. I am not limited to specific cells that are involved with the sync process. So that is what I did as you see below. It is working like a charm.

In this case, I changed the Target.Address to the dropdown cell that is the original source of change and keep the linked P24 and P25 as before and bam, it works as I intended it to work.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
If Target.Address = "$A$4" Then
Application.EnableEvents = False
ActiveSheet.Cells.Cells(25, 16) = ActiveSheet.Cells(24, 16)
Application.EnableEvents = True
Else
If Target.Address = "$A$4" Then
Application.EnableEvents = False
ActiveSheet.Cells(24, 16) = ActiveSheet.Cells(25, 16)
Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
End If
End Sub
```